# How to use Coffeescript on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, coffeescript, go

Does anyone know if it is possible to use Coffeescript on Google App Engine?  If so how can this be done with the app engine Python or Go platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coffeescript compiles to Javascript, which can be run in a web browser.  In that case, App Engine can serve up the resulting javascript.

I don't know of any way to compile coffeescript to python, java or go though, so you can't use it as a server side language.

Comment: Okay .. so what you are saying is that you have to write your Coffeescript locally, compile it, and then upload the resulting Javascript to the server.  Yes?  I was hoping that something like the Rails Coffeescript preprocessor was available on App Engine, and I guess it is not.

Comment: Yes, that's right.
I'm actually still not entirely clear on what your goal is.  It sounds like you're trying to a) write your server code in coffeescript and run that or b) write your webclient code in coffeescript, have your server compile it, and then serve the javascript to your browser.
I didn't think of b) initially.  The answer is still no though, neither are possible.

Comment: If you consider rails, the framework itself takes care of precompiling coffeescript to javascript on the server, and the answer as you mentioned is a no.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

### 1. Script Tag Method

You may use the Coffeescript compiler:

http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js

Add it into your page header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/coffee-script.js" />
<script type="text/coffeescript" src="/your_script.coffee" />
```

Use this method for testing or lite-app

### 2. MediaGenerator for Django

If you use Django frameworks, this may be the best for you:

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-mediagenerator#coffeescript

It will compile your coffeescript and get things done for you!

final few words: I am newbie in development. I only can read JS but like Coffeescipt a lot. After a lot of exploration. I finally choose Ruby on Rails instead of Python on some frameworks. Because asset pipeline is less-config and easy to learn for me. BTW, Python is still my favour language over Ruby XD

Comment: +1 For the script tag. Sadly, MediaGenerator attempts a shell call to the coffescript compiler, which won't work in appengine.

Comment: This is not an answer for the question. App Engine has nothing to do with Javascript or Coffeescript. Safa Alai is confused about server-side and client-side and you did nothing to clarify this for him.